# Plotting multiple datasets with flot using ajax - Data not showing up properly

Tags: ajax, jquery, flot

I am using flot in an attempt to try to plot some data. I had this working with a single dataset, and when I attempted to modify the code to use more than one dataset, I ran into an error I am having a hard time tracking down and it stopped working. I'm sure it's a change that I made, but for the life of me I can not track it down.

The Y-Axis shows -1.0, -0.5, 0, 0.5, and 1.0 - hardly the values Im expecting and there is no X-Axis data. The graph appears blank.

I am trying to accomplish something similar to the reputation graph on StackOverflow, but this will represent different numeric values. The first value of the `data` pair is meant to be a timestamp (I think I have it calculated correctly), and the second value of the `data` pair is the value to be plotted.

I made sure that I do **not** have my values in quotes, which I saw was one of the most common issues out there.

Any feedback or assistance in pointing out the issue would be most appreciated.

**stats.js**

```
function plotField(){
    var field = 'activeUsers,totalUsers';
    var url = '/api/consoleGet_stats?field='+field;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(datasets){
            var i = 0;
            console.log(datasets);
            $.each(datasets, function(key, val){
                val.color=i;
                i++;

                var data = [ $(this) ];
                console.log(data);

                var options = {
                    lines: { show: true },
                    points: { show: true },
                    xaxis: {mode: 'time', timeformat: "%y/%m/%d", tickDecimals: 0, tickSize: 1 }
                };

                var placeholder = $("#placeholder");

                $.plot(placeholder, data, options);
            });
        }
    });   
}
```

**consoleGet_stats.php**

```
<?php
    //simplified for example purposes
    $fields=explode(",",$_REQUEST['field']);

    foreach ($fields as $field){
        $rows=$dbConnect->getRows('select date, ' .$field. ' from websiteStats order by id asc');
        $resultData = array('label' => $field);
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $t = strtotime($row['date']." UTC") * 1000;
            $resultData['data'][]=array($t, (int)$row[$field]);
        }
        $results[]=$resultData;
    }
    die(Json_encode($results));
?>
```

**console output**

```
[Object { label="activeUsers", data=[6]}, Object { label="totalUsers", data=[6]}]
[[Object { label="activeUsers", data=[6], color=0}]]
[[Object { label="totalUsers", data=[6], color=1}]]
```

**returned json from firebug (formatting added for this posting)**

```
[
    {"label":"activeUsers","data":[[1334583090000,26],[1334669491000,26],[1334755893000,26],[1334842290000,26],[1334928691000,26],[1335015093000,26]]},
    {"label":"totalUsers","data":[[1334583090000,150],[1334669491000,170],[1334755893000,193],[1334842290000,200],[1334928691000,225],[1335015093000,257]]}
]
```

---

[image]

Comment: From what I know, `$.plot` takes an array of objects as `data` parameter, but you seem to pass an array of array of object. Also, it's possible to [plot multiple series at once without iterating through them](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/basic.html).

Comment: Well, that is the resulting array structure that comes from decoding the JSON string as even shown in the flot ajax example, unless I am missing something. Also, I am iterating for now to add the colors. That will be handled differently later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the code to a more simplified:

```
function plotField(){
    var field = 'activeUsers,totalUsers';
    var url = '/api/consoleGet_stats?field='+field;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(datasets){
            $.plot($("#placeholder"), datasets);
        }
    });   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing the `data` arguments one by one (which, by the way, overwrites the previous plot), you can plot everything at once. I now understand that you iterate to get the appropriate color, but the way you are doing it right now is no different from the default way flot does it.

If you want other colors, you can specify them in the series data as:

```
{
    "label":"activeUsers",
    "data": xxx,
    "color": 1 // Or e.g. "rgb(255,0,0)"
}
```

When using integers you use the colors generated by flot. Here's a [small fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bFDZk/6/) of the actual plotting process. There I use `minTickSize: [1, "day"]` to specify that each tick should represent one day.

This you should be able to use together with ajax as:

```
function plotField(){
    var field = 'activeUsers,totalUsers';
    var url = '/api/consoleGet_stats?field='+field;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(datasets){
            var options = {
                lines: { show: true },
                points: { show: true },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: 'time', 
                    timeformat: "%y/%m/%d",
                    minTickSize: [1, "day"]
                }
            }
            var placeholder = $("#placeholder");
            $.plot(placeholder, datasets, options);
        }   
    });   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works fine for me is:

**serverAjaxPage.php**

```
<?php
echo '[
       {
           "data": [
               [
                   1220565600000,
                   106.23
               ],
               [
                   1220824800000,
                   106.34
               ]
           ],
           "label": "Oil price ($)"
       },
       {
           "data": [
               [
                   1167606000000,
                   0.758
               ],
               [
                   1167692400000,
                   0.758
               ],
               [
                   1167778800000,
                   0.7547
               ]
           ],
           "label": "USD/EUR exchange rate",
           "yaxis": 2
       }
   ]';
```

(data from [Multiple Axes example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-multiple/index.html))

**clientPage.html**

```
$(function () {

    //Fetch data with AJAX
    function fetchData() {

        // Normally we call the same URL - a script connected to a
        // database - but in this case we only have static example
        // files, so we need to modify the URL.

        $.ajax({
            url: "/serverAjaxPage.php",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: onDataReceived
        });


        function onDataReceived(series) {

            // Load all the data in one pass; if we only got partial
            // data we could merge it with what we already have.
            data = series;

            var options = {
                series: {
                    lines: {
                        show: true,
                    },
                    points: {
                        show: false
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    ticks: 11,
                    tickDecimals: 0,
                    mode: "time",
                    timeformat: "%d-%m-%Y"
                },
                yaxes: [{
                    position: "left"
                }],
                legend: {
                    position: "sw"
                }
            };



            $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);
        }
    }
    //If you want to load data every 10 seconds
    var interval = 10000;

    //Set interval operation
    var tid = setInterval(fetchData, interval);

});
```